# Reposition Layout On The Fly

Tags: android, layout, runtime, position, gravity

Given the main.xml layout below, is it possible to change the "layout_gravity" of the FrameLayout at runtime with the result shown immediately?

My main layout is a LinearLayout and a centered FrameLayout child with two children, a SurfaceView and an ImageView (positioned at the bottom of the frame layout).

I have a menu, that gives the user the option to reposition the frame layout, which should be done by changing layout_gravity to "top", "bottom", or "center".

In order to accomplish this, I use this code to change the gravity at runtime:

```
int mGravity = Gravity.TOP  // gravity determined from menu selection
FrameLayout mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_framelayout);
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mFrameLayout.getLayoutParams()).gravity = mGravity;
```

However, this does not work immediately.  I have only gotten it to work after the user clicks the other menu item, which takes them to the Android Market.  When the user backs out from the market and returns to my app, only then is the new layout drawn according to what the user previously selected.

Am I missing something simple?  How can I force a redraw right after the user selects the position?  What should I invalidate?

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_main"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/my_framelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/surfaceview_default_h"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <SurfaceView 
        android:id="@+id/my_surfaceview" 
        android:layout_width="@dimen/surfaceview_default_w" 
        android:layout_height="@dimen/surfaceview_default_h">           
    </SurfaceView>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/my_imageview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:src="@drawable/someimage" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    </ImageView>

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:id="@+id/mnu_position"
    android:title="@string/position">
    <!-- Position submenu -->
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/grp_position" 
            android:menuCategory="container" 
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item 
                android:id="@+id/mnu_position_top" 
                android:title="@string/top">
            </item>
            <item 
                android:id="@+id/mnu_position_center"
                android:title="@string/center"
                android:checked="true"> 
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/mnu_position_bottom"
                android:title="@string/bottom">
            </item>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/mnu_android_market" 
    android:title="@string/market">
</item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
mFrameLayout.invalidate();
```

after you set the gravity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that had no effect.  I did however discover that if I do a setBackgroundColor() on the main LinearLayout (ll_main) right after I set the gravity, it does update the FrameLayout position accordingly. But it will only do this once.  If I go right back in the menu and select a different position, it fails to reposition again, even though setBackgroundColor() is run again.